# C++ lcov reached unexpected end of file

Tags: c++, code-coverage, lcov

I try to create a coverage report. I use

`make clean all` and `make coverage`.

I have Boost and lcov installed. But when I try `make coverage` it fails with the following error message:

```
Processing components/Project/CMakeFiles/ProjectMainController.dir/dataHandling/savingUnit/Trimmer.cpp.gcda
geninfo: ERROR: /home/user/ProjectFolder/Project/build/source/Project/components/Project/CMakeFiles/ProjectMainController.dir/dataHandling/savingUnit/Trimmer.cpp.gcno: reached unexpected end of file
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/coverage] Error 255
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/rule] Error 2
```

The strange part is: I havent even written any tests for the Trimmer class and there isnt even a TrimmerTest file. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by completly deleting the content of the build folder

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you can try another version of lcov such as version 1.0